# Rails Tutorial localhost can't click "Account" button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am following the Rails Tutorial by Micheal Hartl. I finished chapter 8, but after pushed to git and Heroku, my heroku site works fine, but in my localhost, I can't click the Account dropdown menu.

Here is my Heroku: [heroku site](https://lockijazz-second-app.herokuapp.com)

Here is my Github: [github](https://github.com/lockijazz/sample_app)

Here is _header.html.erb:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I also ran rake db:reset and rake db:test:prepare and restarted the rails server, that seemed to do nothing.

---

Update:

I fixed it. Here is what I did:

- rearranged my application.js "requires" to have jquery first, jquery_ujs second, bootstrap third, and require_tree fourth
- I updated my gemfile's Bootstrap to Bootstrap 2.3 and restarted the server

Comment: I can, what do you mean with can't?

Comment: and it displays the list items.

Comment: I can duplicate this. I cloned your github repo and it doesn't work but it does work on your Heroku site. @juanpastas - are you checking his heroku site, it works on it but it doesn't work locally.

Comment: Do you guys know what the problem could be? Looking at the other threads, it seems like it would be javascript

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution.  There is another similar question that gives conflicting advice, none of which worked for me.  Your solution did.

Comment: @MotGnog It's better to add an answer and accept it.